# Sensor to read data from defective disks

Tags: sensors, hard-drive, data-recovery

I am looking for a sensor that can be used as a reading head for hard disks.Is there a device like that?

Answer (score 1):

The size of the magnetic bit is extremely small. While such tools exist, they are likely incredibly expensive (hundreds of thousands at the very minimum) due to the scale involved. It's cheaper to send the disk to a data recovery company which has these tools for worst-case recovery.